# Finding an explicit constant in finite element error estimates

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Background: In a finite element approximation to the solution of a linear PDEs, estimates on the order of convergence of the approximation to the solution rely on a theorem of Bramble and Hilbert ("Estimation of linear functionals on Sobolev spaces with application to Fourier transforms and spline interpolation ", SIAM J. Numer. Anal., March 1970). They prove their estimate by appealing to a theorem in Morrey's book *Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations*. The theorem is:

> If $G$ is a strongly Lipschitz domain with diameter less than $R$, then there is a constant $C$ depending on dimension, $m$, $p$, and $G$ such that for any $u$ with $\int D^\alpha u = 0$ for $0\leq |\alpha|\leq m-1$, $$ |u|_{W^j_p} \leq CR^{m-j} |u|_{W^{m_p}}$$
>   where $ |\cdot|$ denotes the seminorm on the $m^{th}$ $L^p$ Sobolev space $W^p_q$.

I would like to know what $C$ is, or at least get a useful upper bound on it. Unfortunately, Morrey's proof is by contradiction and so I am left trying to find a constructive proof. The case for dimension one boils down to classical estimates on Taylor series. This has the flavor of Sobolev and Poincare inequalities, so I have been looking through constructive proofs of those and trying to adapt, but so far no luck. I've also tried to retrace through Morrey's proof to try to find the constant, but I've seen nothing there either.

My ultimate aim is  to trace this constant through the proof of error estimates on finite element approximations of eigenvalues to bound the error of some numerical work I've done and verify that a "counterexample" truly is a cointerexample. So even if finding the constant in Morrey's theorem isn't feasible, an explicit constant for the Bramble-Hilbert lemma, or for further in the approximation proof, would help me.